# shell command deal with only one column

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing

I'm really curious: Is there any tool can assist to shell text processing programs -> cut one column out, provide to text processing programs and then paste it back.

For example, I have a file:

```
3f27,tom,17
6d44,jack,19
139a,jerry,7
```

I want to change field 2, remove all aeiou.

I known there are many ways to work around this problem. But why we do not face it?

I want a tool, like:

```
deal-only -d"," -f2 sed 's/[aeiou]//g'
```

This is more clean and powerful.

So, is anybody known such a tool, or similar solution?
If no, I want to create one.

---

As I said above, I known `sed`, or `awk` can deal above problem well.
But when you meet a complex problem, `sed` or `awk` cannot save you.

```
deal-only -d"," -f2 ./ip2country.rb
```

Here, I want to modify column 2 from ip to country.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: awk is very well suited to deal with only a certain column. awk solutions tend to be very clear. After sed and awk, perl or python would be the next powerful tool. And just for a different perspective: spreadsheets like excel or libreoffice are also **very good** at working with columns, they have a rich feature set.

Comment: @Cyrus I updated the problem. And the 2nd request is the real problem I met. I spend lot of time to deal this problem. I want answer, not for show.

Comment: @andlrc Loop is not bad, but it's too slow. And as I said, I cannot accept ip2country script launched again and again. This file is > 400M and compressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the *coprocess* feature of `bash` (see e.g. [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc)):

```
#!/bin/bash

coproc stdbuf -oL sed 's/[aeiou]//g'

while IFS="," read a b c ; do
    echo "${b}" >&${COPROC[1]}
    read -u ${COPROC[0]} b2
    echo "${a},${b2},${c}"
done
```

Some random notes:

- this is not POSIX
- the standard output of process which filters the column data *MUST* be line buffered/unbuffered (this is the `stdbuf -oL` part -- see section "Buffering" in the above-mentioned document)
- (AFAIK) the same effect can be achieved by spawning a background process and [i/o redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)
- (AFAIK) two named pipes linked to single external "resource-heavy" process input/output should work as well
- I am not 100% sure if this is the best way, but it does work for me

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
# script.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
{print $1 "," gensub("[aeiou]+", "", "g", $2) "," $3}
```

Then:

```
awk -f script.awk < data.txt
```

Comment: I known this way, but consider follow problem, you have a script: ip2country, read ip line by line, and output country line by line.

7391238c2 1.2.3.4 aaa xxx bbb
8987c2d3a 2.3.4.5 ddd eee rrr

awk cannot help, sed cannot help too. :p

ip2country is expensive to launch, because it need read a lot of table.